# ¿Como almacenar una imagen en una base de datos de Microsoft Access y despues leerla desde la base de datos?

Tags: java, imagen, ms-access

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto, que dadas las circunstancias mi única opción es usar access, pero me he encontrado con este problema. Desconozco como almacenar una imagen y leerla desde una base de datos Access. 
He buscado en foros que indican que con el siguiente código podría dar solución a mi dicho problema pero que me arroja el siguiente error:
**"javax.imageio.IIOException: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xac 0xed"**
Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.
Anexo el código que realiza la inserción de la imagen y la lectura de la misma:
Este segmento de código realiza el almacenamiento de la imagen en un campo de tipo "OLE".

```
public boolean guardarfoto(String foto) {
    boolean ok=false;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(foto);
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            PreparedStatement pstm =  con.getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into " +
                    " tImagenes(foto) " + " values(?)");                
            pstm.setBinaryStream(1, fis,(int) file.length());
            pstm.execute();
            pstm.close();
            ok=true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    return ok;
}
//metodo  que dado un parametro "id" realiza una consulta y devuelve como resultado
// una imagen
public Image getfoto(String id){
try{
PreparedStatement pstm =  con.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT " +
        " Foto " +
        " FROM tImagenes " +
        " where id = ? ");
     pstm.setString(1, id);
     ResultSet res = pstm.executeQuery();
     int i = 0;
     while(res.next()){
        //se lee la cadena de bytes de la base de datos
        byte[] b = res.getBytes("Foto");
        // esta cadena de bytes sera convertida en una imagen
        data = ConvertirImagen(b);
        i++;
     }
     res.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex);
    }catch(SQLException e){
     System.out.println(e);
}
return data;
}

//metodo que dada una cadena de bytes la convierte en una imagen con extension 
jpeg
private Image ConvertirImagen(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
Iterator readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpeg");
ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
Object source = bis;
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
reader.setInput(iis, true);
ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
return reader.read(0, param);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues he encontrado la respuesta por mi mismo, me puse a investigar mas y encontré otro método que me ha funcionado, si alguien mas pasa por lo mismo aquí esta lo que yo hice y de una manera sencilla:

```
public Image getfoto(String id){

 ImageIcon icono=null;

  try{
      // Se realiza una consulta la base de datos, nos regresara una imagen segun el id que asignemos
     PreparedStatement pstm =  con.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT " +
        " Foto " +
        " FROM tImagenes " +
        " where id = ? ");
     pstm.setString(1, id);
     ResultSet res = pstm.executeQuery();

     // Extraemos el resultado, el resultado se extrae de forma hexadecimal por lo que hay que convertir a bytes
     while(res.next()){

         // Capturamos la imagen en una variable tipo blob que permite extraer los bytes a utilizar
        Blob blob = res.getBlob(1);
        if(blob!=null){
            // Se establece que se tomara un rango de bytes es decir desde el primero hasta el ultimo
            byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());
            BufferedImage img = null;
            // Se hace la lectura de los bytes y se almacena en el BufferedImage posibilitando realizar la conversion a imagen
            img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            // Por ultimo se guarda en una variable Icon listo para ser utilizada la imagen
            icono = new ImageIcon(img);

return icono.getImage();
        }

     }
     res.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex);
    }catch(SQLException e){
     System.out.println(e);
}
return icono.getImage();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!!!!!! , tenia el mismo error de hecho estaba usando el mismo codigo , cambie librerias para actualizarlo a java 8 y termine con ese error ,